# MySQL - category with product count not showing all results

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, inner-join

I am trying to display the count of products along with the category name in the category list.

I was able to achieve this with JOIN, but not all categories are displayed.

I mean the categories with 0 products were not displayed, but I changed the JOIN to LEFT JOIN which displayed only one category with 0 products.
There are two more.

```
SELECT c.id 
     , c.name 
     , count( p.category_id ) product_count 
  FROM category c 
  LEFT 
  JOIN products p 
    ON c.id = p.category_id 
 GROUP 
    BY p.category_id
```

This is the query I am trying to execute.

If anyone has any idea, please guide me.

Comment: LEFT JOIN  is an OUTER JOIN (aka LEFT OUTER JOIN )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should fail because the `GROUP BY` clause is inconsistent with the `SELECT` columns -- `c.id` is not the same as `p.category_id`.  (Older version of MySQL do accept this syntax.)

You are aggregating by a column that has a `NULL` value when there is no match.  You really want to aggregate by a column in the `category` table.  I would recommend:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name , count( p.category_id ) AS product_count
FROM category c LEFT JOIN 
     products p
     ON c.id = p.category_id
GROUP BY c.id, c.name;
```

Note that the `GROUP BY` columns match the unaggregated `SELECT` columns.  Also, the `as id` and `as name` are redundant, so I removed them.

Comment: Thank you @Gordon for the answer and the detailed explanation. This worked.

Answer (score 0):

use this group statement:

```
GROUP BY c.id
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT c.id AS id, c.name AS name, count( p.category_id ) AS product_count FROM category c
LEFT JOIN products p ON c.id = p.category_id
GROUP BY(c.id)